# How do I keep placeholders from hiding when clicking on a input in Firefox?

Tags: css, html, firefox, placeholder

I need some help with Firefox browser issues please?

I have an input with a placeholder:

```
<input id="contact_lastname" type="text" value="" name="contact_lastname" size="45" placeholder="Type your last name" style="-moz-user-select: none; -moz-user-input: disabled; -moz-user-modify: read-only;" autocomplete="off">
```

Only in Firefox, when I click on that input box, the placeholder will disappear and only then does the unselectable part kick in. Is there some way to disable that html5 event that actually makes the placeholder hidden every time I click on the unselectable input?

I have tried these CSS values already:

```
-moz-user-input: disabled
-moz-user-modify: read-only
-moz-user-select: none
user-select: none
```

Am I missing one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not the fact that the placeholders was disappearing, but the fact that is was not coming back when clicking away. I have changed it to actually work like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.fn.disableSelection = function () {
        return this.each(function () {
            if ( $.browser.mozilla ) // Firefox
            {
                $(this).attr('autocomplete', 'off');
                $(this).keydown(function() { return false; });
                $(this).css('MozUserModify', 'read-only');
            }
            else if ( $.browser.webkit ) // Chrome
            {
                $(this).attr('autocomplete', 'off');
                $(this).css('webkitUserModify', 'read');
                $(this).keydown(function() { return false; });
            }
            else if ( $.browser.msie ) // IE
            {
                $(this).keydown(function() { return false; });
            }
            else // Opera, etc.
            {
                $(this).mousedown(function() { return false; });
            }
        });
    };
</script>
```

This will actually prevent the user from inputting data ,(which was the original problem set), and then return false on the keydown event fired.

Answer (score 1):

On the input field:

```
disabled="disabled"
```